# What wrong i did with my form validation

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have simple form with just two fields

```
@Constraints.Required
public String name;
@Constraints.Required
public String slug;
```

rendered as:

```
@helper.form(routes.Add.create()) {
    <input type="text" name="name" id="new-category-name"/>
    <input type="text" name="slug" id="new-category-slug"/>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
}
```

And I have a problem, because when I firstly submit form with no values, I see errors, which is ok, but when after this validation I resubmit my form(this time with values) again I see my errors

I have logger request.body() and form.errors:

```
[debug] application - DefaultRequestBody(Some(Map(name -> ArrayBuffer(name), slug -> ArrayBuffer(slug))),None,None,None,None,None,false)
[debug] application - {name=[ValidationError(name,[error.required],[])], slug=[ValidationError(slug,[error.required],[])]}
```

Thans for your help

My create action:

```
public Result create(){
    categoryForm = categoryForm.bindFromRequest();

    if(categoryForm.hasErrors()){
        return ok(add.render(categoryForm));
    } else {
        Category category = new Category();
        CategoryForm cf = categoryForm.get();
        category.setName(cf.name);
        category.setSlug(cf.slug);
        categoryRepository.save(category);
        return redirect(routes.Edit.edit(category.getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the `create` action

Comment: "when I firstly submit form with no values, I see errors, which is ok, but when after this validation I resubmit my form(this time with values) again I see my errors". What happens when you try to submit a correct form since the beginning ?

Comment: when I submit this form with correct, all is fine and category object is stored in db

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same id and name :

```
<input type="text" id="slug"  name="slug">
```

You should consider using the [play 2 helpers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers). With them, you are sure to create correct forms.

I warn you agianst using field which name is "name" or "id". It generate conflict. I spend a lot of time before I understood that a id which value is id generate jquery errors.

Comment: Even using play helpers is not the solution on my problem

Comment: Did you try typing "clean" then "compile" in the activator command prompt.

Comment: those commands aren't the sollution,since I've switched to built-in helpers my problem is still the same